# Can't establish TCP connection, RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm new to RabbitMQ and I want to run a RabbitMQ server instance on centOS7 using the following command:

```
sudo systemctl start rabbitmq-server
```

The command seemed to take forever and when I stopped the process and checked the log files, everything was ok and it said that rabbit is up and running. But when I try to execute any command using rabbitmqctl I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: unable to perform an operation on node 'rabbit@hostname'. Please see diagnostics information and suggestions below.

Most common reasons for this are:

 * Target node is unreachable (e.g. due to hostname resolution, TCP connection or firewall issues)
 * CLI tool fails to authenticate with the server (e.g. due to CLI tool's Erlang cookie not matching that of the server)
 * Target node is not running

In addition to the diagnostics info below:

 * See the CLI, clustering and networking guides on https://rabbitmq.com/documentation.html to learn more
 * Consult server logs on node rabbit@hostname
 * If target node is configured to use long node names, don't forget to use --longnames with CLI tools

**DIAGNOSTICS**
attempted to contact: [rabbit@hostname]

rabbit@hostname:
  * connected to epmd (port 4369) on hostname
  * epmd reports node 'rabbit' uses port 25672 for inter-node and CLI tool traffic
  * can't establish TCP connection to the target node, reason: timeout (timed out)
  * suggestion: check if host 'hostname' resolves, is reachable and ports 25672, 4369 are not blocked by firewall

Current node details:
 * node name: 'rabbitmqcli-806330-rabbit@hostname'
 * effective user's home directory: /var/lib/rabbitmq
 * Erlang cookie hash: KgAE7WR3dl5/FGAyWKE5LA==
```

I tried killing the processes manually but it didn't work.
every needed port is listening and I can telnet them. Can you please help me on where the problem might be?

Comment: Do you find the rabbitmq ports as `LISTEN` in `netstat -a | grep tcp`? Do you have a firewall? The problem is rather clear, one server can't reach the others server port.

Comment: Yes, They are all in "LISTEN" mode and I don't have a firewall. rabbit is running on one server and there is no clustering.

Comment: Can you resolve the hostname using `host <hostname>` from the client server?

Comment: No, connection timeout is what I get. I already tried changing the hostname to what I get by "hostname" command and putting the result in rabbitmq environment variables file but still no chance. And the hostname in this error didn't change too.

Comment: If the IP address isnt publicly propagated, you have to put the IP/host combination in `/etc/hosts` file. You could also try to connect to the IP address instead of the hostname.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client machine cannot resolve the hostname pointing to the rabbitmq server.

If the IP address isn't publicly propagated, you have to put the IP/host combination in `/etc/hosts` file.

You could also try to connect to the IP address instead of the hostname to clear any other network related issues.